# Alfresco Document management system in spring application

Tags: spring, alfresco

I am new to Alfresco document management system in spring, but I have done Alfresco activity workflowbefore. I want to develop Alfresco DMS in Spring.

Any body did this please send me sample model application or related web site url.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you [try the Alfresco Developer and Documentation site](http://docs.alfresco.com/)? And the [Alfresco Wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/)?

Comment: Do you want to connect your application with `Alfresco` ???

Comment: Yes, i want to connect my application with alfresco

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to connect to your Alfresco Repository

```
private static Session getSession(String serverUrl, String username, String password) {SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(SessionParameter.USER, username);
params.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, password);
params.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, serverUrl);
params.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
List<Repository> repos = sessionFactory.getRepositories(params);
if (repos.isEmpty()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Server has no repositories!");
}
return repos.get(0).createSession(); }
```

you only have to add your `ServerUrl` , `Username` and a `Password` (in default it will be `admin` , `admin` )

Comment: Tell me if you need another method(it's impossible to share all the methods in one post ) example :  I need how to upload a file.

Comment: I will provide an example here non need to send an email serverUrl = "http://ip@:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom"; you have just to add the `Alfresco` Ip Adresse example if it's a local `Alfresco` Installation just make it 127.0.0.1

Comment: any thing new ?!?